# Visual Studio import Matlab lib

Tags: c++

I am trying to import the matlab libraries (\extern\lib\win64\microsoft) into a C++ Project, to use their functionality there. I have done the following up until now:

- Add the header folder to the include directories
- Add the mentioned path to the library directories
- Add to linker/input: "libmx.lib;libmex.lib;libmat.lib"

Matlab and Visual Studio are both 64bit.

Now I try to run the program, but now it says that "libmat.dll" is missing, although I actually added "libmat.lib", why is that? Can anybody help?

Comment: The DLL files have to either be in the same folder as the executable, or in the system `PATH`.

Comment: `Now I try to run the program, but now it says that "libmat.dll" is missing, although I actually added "libmat.lib", why is that? Can anybody help?` from your error libmat.lib is an import library not a static library. An import library needs a .dll file in your path or the same folder as the executable like @JoachimPileborg said above.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I added the path to the dll (\bin\win64) to the PATH variable, as well as in the settings of visual studio (Executable Directories, library directories), but still have the same error.

Comment: ok I solved the problem, the project was on a novell partition, I put it somewhere locally and it worked, thanks guys